# Problem with System.Windows.Automation Namespace

Tags: wpf, expression-blend, ui-automation

I am implementing WPF Application and i want to use System.Windows.Automation Namespace to capture highlgihted text from applications.

The Problem is that Visual Studio and Expression don't identfy AutomationElement, TreeScope, TextPattern and Red underlined it !! i am using Visual Studio 2010 Professional and Expression 4 on Windows 7. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add UIAutomationClient.dll and it's dependencies as references. Even though the namespace is visable, not all of the classes are in the same Assembly.

Comment: It's in the UIAutomationClient Assembly, but it's in the System.Windows.Automation.Text namespace.  Do you have the right namespace for it?

Comment: sorry i missed to include System.Windows.Automation.Text namespace
Thanks man (Y)